# Order of keyboard tab navigation within a form with help links

Tags: website-design, usability, forms

**Situation:**
I am supporting some old web forms and each input box has an icon next to it that opens up a description section directly below the field. Right now, tabbing through the form alternates between the field and the icon to open the help section.

**Question:**
From the first form field, should the tab navigation go sequentially through the fields, skipping the help links completely, OR tab through the help at end of the form?

*I've looked at some [other questions which deal with accessibility and screen readers](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56098/accessibility-keyboard-focus-order-tab-directly-to-form-or-tab-through-all-e) but I'm mostly interested in usability (since there are other accessibility issues and the help content is hidden by default).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paragraph length help hint isn't ideal. But if that is what you have to work with, then: **tabs should skip the help links and go immediately to the next field**.

Keyboard controls is to enable quick navigation through the form. A user quickly going from field to field are unlikely to need to read help links. So it'll be extra unnecessary tabs to complete the form.

Note: This assumes you have a typical user who can directly interact with elements on the screen instead of having keyboard-only input. I assumed that's the case because you said accessibility and screen readers isn't a factor. You're not going to be able to view the help text with only keyboard controls.

---

If it possible to shorten the descriptions though, dynamic "hints" that displays when the input is active would be better.

[image]

[More examples on Patterny](http://patternry.com/p=dynamic-input-hints/)

This solves your keyboard tab navigation issue and also make it so user don't need to go to a new page to view descriptions.

Comment: Some of the descriptions can be quite long (multiple sentences). I've updated the question to describe how the descriptions work. Right now the descriptions display within the page.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for clarifying. I've updated the answer.